# NativeScript Angular: registerElement of custom component with attributes

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to integrate a custom NS core / third party component into an Angular template. The attributes of my component should also be set in the template.

Given the generated sample from `tns`, i have done the following steps:

1. Register my Component:

`registerElement("TestView", () => require("./test-view").TestView);`

2. Create Component:

```js
import observable = require("data/observable");
import stackLayout = require("ui/layouts/stack-layout");
import label = require("ui/label");
import button = require("ui/button");
import { View } from "ui/core/view";
import { Property, PropertyChangeData, PropertyMetadata, PropertyMetadataSettings } from "ui/core/dependency-observable";

export class TestView extends stackLayout.StackLayout {

public static userNameProperty = new Property(
    "userName",
    "TestView",
    new PropertyMetadata("", PropertyMetadataSettings.None)
);

public get userName(): string {
    return this._getValue(TestView.userNameProperty);
}

public set userName(newName: string) {
    this._setValue(TestView.userNameProperty, newName);
}

constructor() {
    super();

    var counter: number = 0;

    var lbl = new label.Label();
    var btn = new button.Button();
    btn.text = "Tap me " + this.userName + "!";
    btn.on(button.Button.tapEvent, (args: observable.EventData) => {
            lbl.text = "Tap " + counter++;
        });

        this.addChild(lbl);
        this.addChild(btn);
    }
}
```

3. Use it in Angular template:

```html
<StackLayout class="p-20">
    <TestView userName="Felix"></TestView>
</StackLayout>
```

The component displays, but the button text does not show "Tap me [userName]", because userName is undefined.

What is the correct way to pass arguments as attributes for the component?

**Update**

Having read [Data Binding](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#binding-source) and [Properties](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/properties), i augmented above code sample with definition of a `userName` property. But its still not set, quite frustrating...
Can anybody give some insight? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working.
There has to be established Data Binding between

1. Angular template and custom Component `TestView` by encapsulating the property `userName` in a `Property` type of the `ui/core/dependency-observable` module (*see above code*).
2. the component and it's button by binding the component's `userName` source property to the button target text property (you can also set this by a default `BindingContext`).

```js
var btn = new button.Button();
var buttonBindingOptions = {
    expression: "'Tap me ' + userName + '!'",
    sourceProperty: "userName",
    targetProperty: "text",
    twoWay: false
};
btn.bind(buttonBindingOptions, this);
```

In the parent `Appcomponent` user can by dynamically set like this:

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
    user : string;

    constructor() {
        this.user = "Felix";

        setTimeout(()=> {this.user = "Other"}, 1000);
    }
}
```

app.html:

```
<TestView [userName]="user"></TestView>
```